# Create a Map in Java that takes maps ints randomly

Tags: java, random, dictionary

I want to have a `Map` in the form:

```
0 -> 1
2 -> 0
1 -> 2
```

Or

```
0 -> 4
1 -> 0
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 1
```

Every int is supposed to be mapped exactly to a distinct int in the range.
I want to pass the function an `int` the size of the Map and get back a `Map` object.
What's a good way to implement this functionality?

Comment: make array 0 .. N, then shuffle it, then put in Map in order from 0 to N. Well, if size is known from the beginning.

Comment: `The most efficient way to implement this functionality would be to not use Java.` Why is that ?

Comment: No reason. Just spam.

Comment: @Christian please specify what your goal is. Speed? Real random distribution? Nice code? Otherwise you won't get good answers and maybe closed down for (the answer) being too opinion based.

Comment: Does it have to be Map? Wouldn't using shuffled array be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Map<Integer,Integer> bijectiveMap(int n) {
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
            values.add(i);
        Collections.shuffle(values);

        Map<Integer,Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
            result.put(i,values.get(i));
        return result;
    }
```

Output for n=10 :

`{0=7, 1=5, 2=3, 3=6, 4=1, 5=4, 6=2, 7=8, 8=9, 9=0}`

Answer (score 1):

A shuffle might do. Possibly not the fastest, but certainly the cleanest way.

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> getRandomMapping(int min, int max){
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //Fill array in order
    for(int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++){
        arr.add(i + min);
    }
    //Shuffle
    Collections.shuffle(arr);

    //Read into map
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++){
        m.put(new Integer(i + min), arr.get(i));
    }

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `Map`. Just shuffle an `Array`/`ArrayList` (initialised with `a[i] = i`). Quality of distribution depends on your shuffle algorithm.

Comment: +1, an array/`ArrayList` is simpler to work with.   If for some reason it really is necessary to return a `Map`, you could create a class that wraps the array and implements the `Map` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If avoid Collections.shuffle. Here

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> foo(final int size) {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> out = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(size*5);
    final List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        values.add(i, i);
    }
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
        out.put(new Integer(i), values.remove(r.nextInt(i)));
    }
    return out;
}
```

1. Create all collections of appropriate size (hashmap load factor here is about 20%, it will eat too much space).
2. Shuffle and add elements in one loop
3. As keySet is not ordered there is no need to go from 1 to N
4. Put Random as transient static, then it would be also faster in some cases.
5. Use Apache collections for int and long, not for Integer wrapper

   ```
   final static transient Random r = new Random();
   final public static Map<Integer, Integer> foo(final int size) {
       final Map<Integer, Integer> out = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(size*5);
       final List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
       int i;

       for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           values.add(i, i);
       }
       for (; i > 0; i--) {
           out.put(new Integer(i), values.remove(r.nextInt(i)));
       }
       return out;
   }
   ```

I apologize for List loops, it was too much std::vector for today. Fast solution

```
final static transient Random rand = new Random();
final public static Map<Integer, Integer> foo(final int size) {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> out = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(size*5);
    final Integer[] values = new Integer[size];
    int i, r;
    for (i = 0; i <size; i++) {
        values[i] = i;
    }
    for (; i > 0; i--) {
        r = rand.nextInt(i);
        out.put(i, values[r]);
        values[r] = values[i-1];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Your implementation, size = 100_000 : 1557 ms, size = 1_000_000 : 167130 ms. Implentation using Collections.shuffle, size = 100_000 : 95 ms, size = 1_000_000 : 2934 ms. Much faster, you said ? Removing the elements of `values` has a terrible cost whereas Collections.shuffle only swap elements. Anyway !

Comment: The question is solved, I don't want to start a debate. All I want to say is that removing an element to an ArrayList is O(n) so you last loop is O(n^2), whereas Collections.shuffle is O(n). Period. Try by yourself ! http://pastebin.com/Se7CugK4